# In C# Service-Bus-Trigger Functions, can I get `ServiceBusMessageActions` through "normal" dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, containers, azureservicebus

I have a Function App built in C# which handles messages from the service bus in batches.
It has its own logic what to complete, abandon, or dead-letter.

Currently, I am using an instance of `ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions` which I get from the Function's paramaters, like:

```
    public List<(ServiceBusReceivedMessage, SalesforceRecord)> SelectValidMessages(
                ServiceBusReceivedMessage[] messages,
                ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions
            )
```

However, `messageActions` is not getting consumed in this class, but rather by various methods of `ServiceBusReceivedMessageHelper serviceBusReceivedMessageHelper`.

Presently, I am passing `messageActions` to whatever method when I call it, and then it needs to be passed until it needed.

Normally, I inject instances of classes into the classes where they are consumed like:

```
    public ServiceBusReceivedMessageHelper(
            ILogger<ServiceBusReceivedMessageHelper> logger,
            MeterExchangeFeedbackConfig meterExchangeFeedbackConfig,
            SalesforceContractResolver salesforceContractResolver
        )
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _meterExchangeFeedbackConfig = meterExchangeFeedbackConfig ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(meterExchangeFeedbackConfig));
        _salesforceContractResolver = salesforceContractResolver ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(salesforceContractResolver));
    }
```

and use the Startup class to control their instantiation, like:

```
        _ = services.AddLogging(logBuilder => logBuilder.AddSerilog(logger))
            .AddSingleton<ServiceBusReceivedMessageHelper>()
            .AddSingleton<SalesforceContractResolver>()
            .AddSalesforceCache(configuration)
            .AddSingleton<SalesforceCacheHelper>();
```

However, if I try adding `.AddSingleton<ServiceBusMessageActions>()` to the above and similarly injecting `ServiceBusMessageActions`, this results in a runtime error like:

```
DryIoc.ContainerException: Unable to get constructor of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.ServiceBusMessageActions using provided constructor selector when resolving singleton Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.ServiceBusMessageActions {ServiceKey=DefaultKey(1), ReturnDefault} as parameter "messageActions" #146
in singleton Enpal.LackmannServiceBusToSalesforceCacheTranscriber.Helpers.ServiceBusReceivedMessageHelper {ReturnDefault} #147
from scoped container with {no name}.
at DryIoc.ReflectionFactory.CreateExpressionOrDefault(Request request) in D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs:line 7010
at DryIoc.Factory.GetExpressionOrDefault(Request request) in D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs:line 6564
```

(snipped for brevity)

I tried to use `ServiceBusReceiver` instead with similar result.

Is there something I can/should do so I can Complete, Abandon, or DeadLetter messages in a helper class without needing to pass `ServiceBusMessageActions` around so much, but rather injecting it only where it is needed?

Comment: No, it is not possible to use `SerivceBusMessageActions` in that way.  The actions are bound to the specific receiver associated with messages emitted to the Function.   Service Bus messages can only be settled on the same AMQP link that they were received - you would not be able to use the actions or a `ServiceBusReceiver` to settle other messages.

Comment: @JesseSquire, Thanks for the response.  That seems like a design flaw to me.  Any idea why this limitation exists?  Shouldn't the message contain all the information needed to complete it on the service bus?

Comment: This is a limitation based on how the service is implemented.  Unfortunately, I don't have deeper insight than that.  Your best bet for more information or registering feedback would be to [open an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).